# Continuum limit for volume

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given the probability density

$$\rho = \frac{i\hbar}{2mc^2}(\psi^*\partial_t\psi - (\partial_t\psi^*)\psi) = |\mathcal{N}|^2|\Xi|^2$$

where $\mathcal{N}$ is a (real) normalization constant and $\Xi$ does not depend on $\vec{x}$.

If we want to normalize it such that we find one particle in a volume $V$, we demand

$$\int_V \mathrm{d}x^3|\mathcal{N}|^2|\Xi|^2 = V |\mathcal{N}|^2|\Xi|^2$$

and therefore $\mathcal{N} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V|\Xi|^2}}$

How can I get the continuum limit of this? I've seen $V\rightarrow (2\pi\hbar)^3$ but this does not work out with the units. Also, what would be the idea behind this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by continuum limit here? It looks like you are already dealing with a continuous $x$. Do you mean the infinite volume limit?

Comment: Sorry, I meant going from quantum to classical.